# I have written this equation with for loop. anyone got any idea about other forms to write this equation?

Tags: python, math, factorial

### equation : 1 + 1/2! + 1/3! + 1/4! ... + 1/n! --> (n < 10)

```
#define factorial

def fact(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return x * fact(x-1)
```

#---------Long way------------

```
#equation= 1 + 1/fact(2) + 1/fact(3) + 1/fact(4) + 1/fact(5) + 1/fact(6)+ 1/fact(7) + 
#1/fact(8)+ 1/fact(9) 
#print(equation)
```

#---------with for Loop-------

```
s = 1
for x in range (2,10) :
  s += (1/fact(x))
print(s)
```

#-----------------------------

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its always gonna be n < 10, then why compute factorial each time,

```
s = 1
y = 9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2
j = 9
while j >1:
  s += (1/y)
  y = y/j
  j = j-1
print(s)
```

Or compute factorial only for the n-th number and do the same as above.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it is using `math.fact`

```
import math
s = 1
for x in range (2,10) :
  s += (1/math.fact(x))
print(s)
```